# How do you 'jump to definition' in a fresh install of LightTable, without setting your hair on fire

Tags: lighttable

I tried `ctrl-` which was suggested somewhere online, but that makes the font smaller. (`ctrl+` though does not undo that, so I had to restart LightTable to get back to normal).

Pressing `ctrl enter` I can manage to write and use "jump to definition", but obviously I will not be going through that every time....

If this should have helped, it is rather confusing what the period and comma here mean:
[image]

So do the built-in default keyboard shortcuts allow that, and how do they allow *increasing* font size?

Comment: "ctrl-x" is a common way to write "press and hold down the Control key and then press the 'x' key". Tho maybe we should use `<kbd>` tags to be more visually explicit for anyone not familiar with that convention.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hit `cmd/ctrl` + `enter`
2. in the pane that this brought in: type "jump to" to see the command "jump to...", plus its keyboard shortcut. you can select the command from there but that would suck if it were the only way to invoke commands, so observer the keyboard binding you get there: (in the blue circles below)

   [image]
3. notice that keys are separated by dashes in the display of the keyboard shortcut, so *do not actually enter a dash because it is not part of the command and you will be doing crazy stuff if you assume otherwise*
4. same thing for finding out how to zoom: enter "zoom" in that pane
5. unset you hair on fire

Courtesy of @rundis from the gitter channel...